# run script after reboot

Tags: scripts, cron

I have the following script that should run mongo DB server and run my application after reboot

here is the script that I wrote :

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
cd airnotifier/
sudo python3 ./app.py
```

and then I add this script to crontab to schedule it to run on reboot

```
@reboot /home/user/project/script.sh
```

then I reboot the machine using the command

```
sudo reboot
```

but nothing happen, can anyone please tell me what is the problem ?

Comment: Why sudo? How do you expect to enter your password?

Comment: the two commands should run with sudo command to run the servers, but I do not know how to enter the password, I asked before a question about how to enter password but I did not get reply yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Don't do that!

There are two things wrong with your approach.

1. Don't start a systemd service using cron! Systemd has its own method to start services when the computer starts/restarts.
2. Don't use `sudo` inside a script that will be used in a cron job. You will also need to provide the full path to the files/programs.

## 1. Use `enable`

Since `mongod` is already a systemd service, you don't need to start it at system restart manually. It should start automatically. If it does not start, use the following command **only once**:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

**Note.** Once you use this command, the mongod.service should start automatically when the computer starts.

If for some reason this does not work, update your question with more details, such as what errors you get when you use the above command.

## 2. Use `sudo crontab e`

When you want a script to run with admin privilege via `cron`, do not put `sudo` in the script.

**Remove the existing line using `crontab -e`.**

Then use the command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then add the following line in the file:

```
@reboot /home/user/project/script.sh
```

where the script.sh should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /full/path/to/airnotifier/
/usr/bin/python3 /full/path/to/airnotifier/app.py
```

The reason you need the full path, such as `/home/USER/project/airnotifier/` is because when the `cron` will start as the `root` user (remember the `sudo` before the `crontab -e`) then it will not start in your user directory.

The other thing about cron is that it does not have all the environmental variables like the full PATH. So you may need the path to the `python3` command as well.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I want to add two more notes, that I should chmod of my script file to be 777 and also make sure it does not have any /r hidden characters, so I used this command <sed -i 's/\r//g' script.sh> to remove any hidden character and then it works

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail I am glad that you got the script to work. I don't know why you needed to chmod your script to 777. I never had to do that. I didn't know or have any hidden characters in my scripts.

Comment: when I run it without chmod it gives me Permission denied, I had a hidden character because I used an editor for windows to write my script, that is why it has some hidden characters like \r, Thanks for your help

Comment: Okay, that's fine.